# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): planets.filter is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I was using redux to manage state.

In my app.js,there is a promise function.

It is used to get the planet's name、diameter and rotation_period

Here is problem after i changed this promise function into

```
 this.props.onRequestPlanets():
```

deleted constructor() and set planets、isPending to this.props

My website showed the error

Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): planets.filter is not a function

Here is the picture:

[image]

What should I do?

the Promise function in app.js:

```
   componentDidMount() {
           const urls = [
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/',
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=2', 
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=3',
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=4',
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=5',
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=6',
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=7'
    ]

    Promise.all(urls.map(async url => {
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const morePlanets = await response.json();
        var combinedArrayOfPlanets = this.state.planets;
        combinedArrayOfPlanets.push(morePlanets.results);

        var sortedArrayOfPlanets = combinedArrayOfPlanets
            .flat()
            .sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));

        this.setState({planets: sortedArrayOfPlanets})
    }))
    .catch(error => 
        console.log('Error during fetching of planets:', error)
    );
}
```

my app.js:

```
  import React,{Component} from 'react';
  import {connect} from 'react-redux';
  import CardList from '../Components/CardList';
  import SearchBox from '../Components/SearchBox';
  import Scroll from '../Components/Scroll';
  import './App.css';
  import {setSearchField,requestPlanets} from '../action'

  const mapStateToProps=state=>{
      return{
         searchField:state.searchPlanets.searchField,
         planets:state.requestPlanets.planets,
         isPending:state.requestPlanets.isPending,
         error:state.requestPlanets.error
       }
     }

 const mapDispatchToProps=(dispatch)=>{
 return {
    onSearchChange:(event)=>dispatch(setSearchField(event.target.value)),
    onRequestPlanets:()=>dispatch(requestPlanets())
 }
  }




class App extends Component{
 componentDidMount() {
     this.props.onRequestPlanets();
}

render()
    const {searchField,onSearchChange,planets,isPending}=this.props;
     if (isPending) {
        return <div className='tc'><h1>Loading</h1></div>;
     }
    const filteredPlanets = planets.filter(planet=>{
        return planet.name.toLowerCase().includes(
            searchField.toLowerCase())
            ||
            planet.diameter.toLowerCase().includes(
                searchField.toLowerCase())
            ||
            planet.rotation_period.toLowerCase().includes(
                searchField.toLowerCase())
    })
    return (
    <div className='tc'>
        <h1 className='f2'>StarWarPlanet</h1>
        <SearchBox searchChange={onSearchChange}/>
        <Scroll>
            <CardList planets = {filteredPlanets}/>
        </Scroll>
    </div>
    );
    }
 }

 export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

my action.js:

```
 import{
CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
REQUEST_PLANETS_PENDING,
REQUEST_PLANETS_SUCCESS,
REQUEST_PLANETS_FAILED 
  }from './constants.js'

 export const setSearchField=(text)=>({
type:CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
payload:text
 })

  export const requestPlanets = ()=>(dispatch)=>{
dispatch({type:REQUEST_PLANETS_PENDING})
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/planets/')
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=2') 
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=3')
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=4')
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=5')
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=6')
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=7')
    .then(response =>response.json())
    .then(data =>dispatch({type:REQUEST_PLANETS_SUCCESS,payload:data}))
    .then(error =>dispatch({type:REQUEST_PLANETS_FAILED,payload:error}))
 }
```

my reducers.js:

```
  import{
CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD,
REQUEST_PLANETS_PENDING,
REQUEST_PLANETS_SUCCESS,
REQUEST_PLANETS_FAILED 
  }from './constants.js'

   const initialStateSearch={
     searchField:''
  }

  export const searchPlanets=(state=initialStateSearch,action={})=>{
    switch(action.type){
      case CHANGE_SEARCH_FIELD:
        return Object.assign({},state,{searchField:action.payload})
     default:
        return state;
    }
 }

const initialStatePlanets={
    isPending:false,
     planets:[],
     error:''
}

export const requestPlanets = (state=initialStatePlanets,action={})=>{
    switch(action.type){
        case REQUEST_PLANETS_PENDING:
          return Object.assign({},state,{isPending:true})
         case REQUEST_PLANETS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({},state,{planets:action.payload,isPending:false})
    case REQUEST_PLANETS_FAILED:
      return Object.assign({},state,{error:action.payload,isPending:false})
    default:
      return state;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Did it work before trying to move this to Redux?

Comment: In your original promise function you are mapping over the array of urls which is correct, but in the fetch you are not. you need to make a separate fetch for each url

Answer (score 0):

fetch expects an object as a second argument. The error comes when you are doing in your action:

```
fetch('https://swapi.co/api/planets/',
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=2', 
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=3',
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=4',
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=5',
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=6',
        'https://swapi.co/api/planets/?page=7')
```

You are adding strings as second, third... argument which is wrong.

Also, as you are now saving the request data in the store and receiving it via the mapStateToProps you should change in your render:

```
const {planets} = this.state;
```

to:

```
const {planets} = this.props;
```

Also, be careful when doing:

```
var combinedArrayOfPlanets = this.state.planets;
```

The state should be immutable and you are not creating new object here but just adding to combinedArrayOfPlanets a reference to this.state.planets. So when you are later changing combinedArrayOfPlanets you are really changing the state. You could do something like that though:

```
var combinedArrayOfPlanets = [...this.state.planets];
```

Also, you should get the planets from the store the same way you create them in the initial state, instead of:

```
planets:state.requestPlanets.planets,
```

should be:

```
planets:state.planets,
```

That way you will get the planets from the reducer but not the extra planets you have in the .json file. I recommend you to add those extra planets from the .json in the reducer just before saving them into the store.

Comment: After i use fetch to every each url,,my website becomes loading all the time.What should I do?

Comment: If you use "await" to wait for the Promise of each fetch to resolve, then you do not need the Promise.all() or otherwise you will have to create another Promise inside and resolve it when you need.

Comment: Also, if you are using Redux to keep the state and receiving the store data via the mapStateToProps (which seem you are doing already fine), then you should get the "planes" from the props not from the local state. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I did what you said but my website becomes all white.It shows nothing.What should i do?

Comment: You can start by adding a breakpoint on the first line of your render() and see what values this.props has each time it stops. It should be completing the props you have set on mapStateToProps. If those do not change, then add a breakpoint on your reducer to see if data is being saved correctly in the REQUEST_PLANETS_SUCCESS case.

Comment: it comes out an error said Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): planets.filter is not a function

Comment: You have other issues now, the main one is you are mixing local state with redux state and you are breaking the immutability of the state.. let me try to update my answer.

Comment: So my promise function shouldn't delete in componentDidMount()?I have already replace promise function into this.props.onRequestPlanets()